# Submitting form that has tinymce textarea, radio button and checkbox to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

My form has several textarea fields, radio button, checkbox and a select input. If I do not use TinyMCE on the textarea, I can easily submit the form using php. When I decided to use TinyMCE on one textareas, I brought in java script to process TinyMCE and to stop the page refreshing at submitting. Now when I submit, it seems only the last php line of code will be processed saying 'Please select at least one correct answer!'.
  Below are my codes.

```
<form id="myform2" method="post" action="insert_question_refresh.php">
    <p style="color:#333">Question</p>
    <textarea class="tinymce" name="texteditor" id="texteditor"></textarea>

    <p style="color:#333" style="margin-top:30px !important">Answers</p>

    A<input type="checkbox"name="get_value[]" value="A"><span class="ans_option"> This answer option is correct</span>
    <textarea name="aaa" class="form-control" style="width:60% !important; height:200px !important"></textarea>

    B <input type="checkbox" name="get_value[]" value="B"><span class="ans_option"> This answer option is correct</span>
    <textarea name="bbb" class="form-control" style="width:60% !important; height:200px !important"></textarea>

    C <input type="checkbox"name="get_value[]" value="C"><span class="ans_option"> This answer option is correct</span>
    <textarea name="ccc" class="form-control" style="width:60% !important; height:200px !important"></textarea>

    D<input type="checkbox" name="get_value[]" value="D"><span class="ans_option"> This answer option is correct</span>
    <textarea name="ddd" class="form-control" style="width:60% !important; height:200px !important"></textarea>

    <label for="student_id" class="control-label" style="color:#333" >Course Title</label>
    <select name="category" class="form-control" required>
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>three</option>
    </select>

    <p style="color:#333" style="margin-top:23px !important">Randomize answer?</p>
    <input name="random" type="radio" value="no" /> <span style="color:#333; font-size:14px">No</span><br>
    <input name="random" type="radio" value="yes" /> <span style="color:#333; font-size:14px">Yes</span>

    <button id="sub" style="color:#fff; padding:5px 66px" class="btn btn-success" ><b>Save</b></button>

</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    include("includes/db.php");
    if(!empty($_POST["get_value"])){
    foreach($_POST["get_value"] as $checkbox){
    }
    $question = $_POST['texteditor'];
    $a = $_POST['aaa'];
    $b = $_POST['bbb'];
    $c = $_POST['ccc'];
    $d = $_POST['ddd'];
    $random = $_POST['random'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];

    $insert_question = "insert into questions (question,checkbox,ansa,ansb,ansc,ansd,random,category) values ('$question','$checkbox','$a','$b','$c','$d','$random','$category')";

    $run_question = mysqli_query($con, $insert_question);
    if($insert_question){
    echo "Your message was successfully delivered";
    }
    else {
     echo "failed";
    }
    }

    else{
    echo "<script>alert('Please select at least one correct answer!')</script>";
    }

?>
```

Java Script

```
 $("#sub").click( function() {

 $.post( $("#myform2").attr("action"), $("#myform2 :input").serializeArray(), function(info){ $("#result").html(info); } );
clearInput();
 });

 $("#myform2").submit( function() {
    return false;
 });

 function clearInput() {
     $("#myform2 :input").each( function() {
         $(this).val('');
     });
 }
```

insert_question_refresh.php is the php page. Java script is on the same page with the form. Please what do i do to these codes to submit my form?

Comment: Try changing `$("#myform2 :input").serializeArray()` to just `$("#myform2").serialize()`

Comment: Please read up on SQL injection attacks; your code is vulnerable. You should use parameterised queries to avoid this.

Comment: Rory McCrossan's suggestion submitted the contents of the form, but it doesn't submit the textarea that has tinyMCE, the first text area.

Answer (score 0):

To submit all the information, you must add a new input in your HTML code, it should be the last input inside your form. You should add an attribute to this input with the type submit. It would be like this,

```
<p style="color:#333" style="margin-top:23px !important">Randomize answer?</p>
    <input name="random" type="radio" value="no" /> <span style="color:#333; font-size:14px">No</span><br>
    <input name="random" type="radio" value="yes" /> <span style="color:#333; font-size:14px">Yes</span>

    <button id="sub" style="color:#fff; padding:5px 66px" class="btn btn-success" ><b>Save</b></button>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

I hope you found your answer.

Comment: Adding a new input with an attribute submit does not work for me.